# Как сделать чтобы функция срабатывала через какое то время или по определенному действию Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет. 
Делаю бота для тг и столкнулся с проблемой. 
Как сделать чтобы функция срабатывала через какое то время или по определенному действию?

Comment: Через какое-то время после чего? Что является "действием"?

Comment: Через какое то время после того как я введу команду в чат
Действе -   нажатие на кнопку телегарама

Answer (score 0):

Если асинхронный бот, то

```
loop.call_later(delay, callback, *args)
```

или

```
loop.call_at(when, callback, *args)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#scheduling-delayed-callbacks

Если синхронный

```
t = threading.Timer(delay, functools.partial(callback, *args ))
t.start()
```